# C++: std::istream read and its calls to std::streambuf underflow

Tags: c++, istream, streambuf

the following code simply tests how often `underflow` is called when using `std::istream` `read` on an `std::stringbuf`.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <sstream>

class TestStringBuf : 
public std::stringbuf
{
public:

    int_type underflow()
    {
        std::cout<<"TestStringBuf underflow"<<std::endl;
        return std::stringbuf::underflow();
    }
};

int main(int argc, const char * argv[])
{
    TestStringBuf buf;
    std::iostream stream(&buf);

    stream << "tesr";

    std::vector<char> data(4);
    stream.read(&data[0], 4);

    for(int i=0; i<data.size(); ++i)
        std::cout<<data[i];
    std::cout<<std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

the output is:

```
TestStringBuf underflow
TestStringBuf underflow
test
```

I expected underflow to be called only once, since I read exactly the amount of bytes present in the get area, so why should it underflow again? Is this the expected behavior?
I am asking because my custom `underflow` method can potentially block for a long time to read new data, so the second call to `underflow` is not very desirable in this case.

I am on Osx using **clang 3.1** and **libc++**.

Thank you!

**Update:**

I just made a completely seperate test and it seems to me that this is a weirdness in the **libc++** implementation since this does not happen with **libstd++**. can someone test this with other implementations? is this a bug or just an implementation difference (feels pretty buggy to me). I updated the code above so you can copy and paste it into any main.cpp.

**Update2:**

After all it was a bug in libc++, see: http://llvm.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=13113 . If you compile libc++ yourself the bug should be gone, I will try that soon.

Comment: Maybe it calls underflow when it goes past position 3 to the end of the stream?

Comment: but why should it go past position 3? I would expect it to go past position 3 in a subsequent call to get() or read() and its siblings.

Answer (score 0):

The C++ standard explicitly allows the implementation of std::basic_stringbuf to store the character sequence in a std::basic_string instead of using the internal buffer of std::basic_streambuf.

Comment: I am not sure how this relates to the question. I only chose stringbuf for the example simplicity. The behavior is identical when inheriting from std::streambuf directly. Could you elaborate what you mean?

Comment: std::streambuf provides an interface for buffered access to a character sequence somewhere else (RAM, file, TCP stream, ...). But the standard doesn't specify how much buffering to use.

Comment: yeah I know, i noticed this behavior when working on a custom std::streambuf for tcp sockets. underflow is called too early in libc++ which can cause very long blocks for no reason.

Comment: Maybe it helps to set a bigger buffer with std::streambuf::pubsetbuf. Don't forget to check return value to be non-null and to delete that buffer after the lifetime of the std::streambuf object. I've never tried that, so I don't know if it helps and if it has any more pitfalls.