# std::basic_istream or std::basic_streambuf

Tags: c++, stream

Well I'm heavenly confused right now; When would anyone use a streambuffer over a stream - or otherwise?

Reading [cppreference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_streambuf) and some online topics regarding this only added to the confusion. To me it seems `std::basic_istream` is an "abstraction" of the buffer. So that one should not have to deal with localization etc.
But you still have to do this when reading file data - so what does it actually abstract away?

On the other hand, what does `std::basic_streambuf` bring?

And then there's the `std::istream_iterator` and `std::istreambuf_iterator`. Which both read elements from the "stream". This adds more confusion: is there any difference in above iterators?

PS: using `istream` here, but could of course also be `ostream` or anything else.
PPS: I should add that confusion was added while googling for examples such as [this stackoverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22109905/why-is-this-stream-buffer-not-working)

Comment: The stream buffer if what is used by the stream to buffer the input/output. In other words, a stream object uses a buffer object. You should not use a buffer object directly.

Comment: One case when you want to use `streambuf` is when implementing your own iostream-derived class.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[std::basic_istream](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_istream) defines user interface: `operator>>`, `read`, etc. That's what you call when you want to do input.

[std::basic_streambuf](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_streambuf) defines virtual member functions: `underflow`, `sync`, etc. That's what you derive from when you want to write your own input class. [boost.iostreams](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/release/libs/iostreams/doc/index.html) makes it easy.

[std::istream_iterator](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/istream_iterator) calls `operator>>` (so it interprets the input as a sequence of objects of some type for which operator>> is defined, goes through locale, skips whitespace, etc)

[std::istreambuf_iterator](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/istreambuf_iterator) accesses a streambuf directly (so it can only read characters, no locale involved, whitespace isn't special)

Comment: Hmm that makes a little sense, but if what about the special case of reading a file opened through ios_mode::binary then? Also I guess for getting the BOM-mask when reading a file one should then use the buf-iterator?

Comment: @paul23 What's so special about it? What does BOM have to do with your question? (in C++11, that's taken care of [by codecvt](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/locale/codecvt_utf16)). Sounds like you have a more specific question in mind.

Comment: Well the exact question I have is found http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4761529/efficient-way-of-reading-a-file-into-an-stdvectorchar there. It uses streambuf iterators, but why doesn't it open the file in binary mode and then read using normal iterators?